# Google Sheets - Conditional Formatting - Shading as hours go by

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have schedule about 20 hours a day for 5 days. Each row is an hour. I want to gray out each row as the hours go by and highlight the current hour green. I have the date/time (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss) in column F displaying as HH:MM:SS.

I seem to have figured out the graying out part. I've used the NOW function in a hidden cell and set my conditional formatting to =$F5<$AK$1
F5 being my first time and AK1 being the hidden NOW() function). When I tried using =$F5<NOW() it was graying out things on parts of the schedule that represented other days. But my new formula seems to work.
For the highlighting of the current hour I started off using custom formula =HOUR($F5)=HOUR(NOW()). This highlights the current hour but also highlights the current hour on other days. I've tried AND statements to check the Date and Time of the cell vs NOW() but nothing seems to only highlight the current hour of the current day.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: please share a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform) with example of your data and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact format of your cells, but given your formula works, I'd suggest to add a condition to compare the days:

```
=AND(HOUR($F5)=HOUR(NOW()),DATEVALUE($F5)=DATEVALUE(TODAY()))
```

As you can see, this tomorrow's value isn't highlighted, but today's (06 feb) is:

[image]

---

UPDATE

Given your spreadsheet and format, you can use the date with TEXT:

=AND(HOUR($A1)=HOUR(NOW()),DATEVALUE(TEXT($A1,"MM/DD/YYYY"))=DATEVALUE(TODAY()))

You could also use `YEAR($A1)=YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH($A1)=MONTH(TODAY())` etc...

[image]

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks! I think I originally used DATE() to try to get it follow the date per row. I've tried your formula and it I'm not getting any highlighting. Would the fact that the cell shows only the time be the issue? I've entered the date and time in the cell but I have it set to display as just the time (ie: 8:00 or 14:00). I've tried to upload a small piece of the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ACds9MhsWsCkjTEFgaXbpJnZlczjAxFx3DpArTqirUM/edit?usp=sharing